# Exception Handling in Spring Framework JNDI

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jndi

```
 I have configured JNDI reference in spring-context.xml ,created JNDI in Websphere application server 7.5, this working fine, but if its database is down, I am not able to start the web application ,i am getting 500 uncaught servlet initialization exception .

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="${reports_db_jndi_ref}"/>
</bean>
```

Could you please advise ? How to handle the exception or how to start the web application even though the database is down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the lookupOnStartup property to false so that Spring returns a proxy to the datasource instead of the actual datasource. However if your application uses the datasource as part of the startup process e.g due to some dependency trying to connect to the database still the looup will occur. Change as follows

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="${reports_db_jndi_ref}"/>
    <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="false"/>
</bean>
```